# Load .tsv with SQL loader

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am trying to load a tsv file with variable length and blanks but I cannot load it.

My TSV file has:

```
code   name   information surname   
1234   Peter              Peter
1111   Carl   exampleexample example Jhon
```

I'm trying with:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'EXAMPLE.TSV'
    INTO TABLE PERSON
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
    (
     CODE,
     NAME,
     INFORMATION,
     SURNAME
     )
```

Comment: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` isn't going to work well for a tab-delimited file ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example.

```
SQL> desc person
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CODE                                               NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)
 INFORMATION                                        VARCHAR2(30)
 SURNAME                                            VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```

Control file; note `fields terminated by x'09'`. I included sample data into the control file itself, for simplicity.

```
options (skip=1)
load data 
infile *
replace
into table person
fields terminated by x'09'
( 
code,
name,
information,
surname
)

begindata
code    name    information surname
1234    Peter       Peter
1111    Carl    example exa John
```

Testing:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test18.ctl log=test18.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri Tra 29 20:26:06 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * From person;

      CODE NAME       INFORMATION                    SURNAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
      1234 Peter                                     Peter
      1111 Carl       example exa                    John
```